# Spring MVC Image response content type set text/html

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, content-type

I have simple controller method to return image like

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> get(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {

    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = null;

     MyImage image = getImage(id);
     HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
     String contentType = image.getContentType();
     if (contentType != null) {
        respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(contentType));
      } 
      respHeaders.setContentLength(image.getLength());
      respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", image.getFilename());

      InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(fileInfo.getInputStream());
      response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);          

      return response;          
}
```

It image has content-type, it will be setted and response has corrent header with correct content-type, but if content-type is not setted, client side response has content-type text/html.

I like to remove content-type header if content-type is unknown but even removing content-type header from header map does not help. Any ideas what would be wrong? Spring version is 3.2.14.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces), you can write something like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "image/*")
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE})
```

without specifying content type in ResposeEntity